# Cannot operate on an array of structures which comprise a string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, structure

I have a structure which includes a `string` field. I create an array of those structures and then I want to pass them to a function (by reference). Everything works perfectly fine when I comment out the `string` field, but if I don't the program crashes. I can't find an answer to this anywhere..

Here's the code (I reduced it to only show the issue):

```
struct student {
    int a;
    int b;
    string name[20];
    char status;
};

void operation(student the_arr[1],int number_of_students) {
    delete[] the_arr;
    the_arr = new student[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        the_arr[i].a = i+5;
        the_arr[i].b = i+4;
    }   
}

int main() {    
    student *abc;
    abc = new student[0];
    operation(abc, 0);  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I need the array to be dynamic so I can change its' size when I need to.

Comment: You should use a vector.

Comment: Yes, use a C++ container like a vector.

Comment: `new student[0]`,  `void operation(student the_arr[1],...` : WAT?

Comment: Also, why does your student have 20 names?

Comment: Can i do it without using vectors?

Comment: Of course you *can* do it without vectors, but *why*?

Comment: string name[20];, it should be string name;, forgot to delete that [20]

Comment: @us2012, probably homework?

Comment: Use `vector` and save us all trouble.

Comment: "  
Compiling with GCC warns that abc is used uninitialized until you change new student[0] to new student[naturalNumber]"
thanks, silly me
but when i commented out the string it worked even with 'new student[0]"..

Comment: @DamianWoroszył, I'm guessing that was a bug, seeing as how Clang and 4.8.0 don't. I thought you could use a size of 0 in a dynamic array. Anyway, there's probably some undefined behaviour somewhere else. Does *this* code and this code only crash?

Comment: Can't see any reason your code would crash.

Comment: @chris it only crash when there is string in structure and i use size 0

Comment: @DamianWoroszył I agree with chris, looks like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't use `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated arrays follow the answer below. In any other case you should use the containers provided by the standard library.

*Note: Your program doesn't crash. The only things the compiler will complain about it the `allocating zero elements` part, but will let you compile and run this program.*

Your function is completely wrong. When using dynamic allocation you can simply pass a pointer like this:

```
void operation(student* the_arr, int number_of_students) {
```

Then inside your function you are dynamically allocating memory which is stored inside the `the_arr` pointer which is not passed by reference therefore leading to the creation of a local pointer variable that will lose the pointer after its execution:

```
void operation(student*& the_arr [...]
```

I suggest you to avoid the below solution though and return the new pointer instead:

```
student* operation(student* the_arr, int number_of_students) {
    delete[] the_arr;
    the_arr = new student[3];
    [...] 
    return the_arr; // <----
}
```

Allocating `abc = new student[0];` doesn't make any sense. You are trying to allocate an array of 0 elements. Maybe you meant `abc = new student[1];`?

Comment: While problems, they shouldn't make a difference with the posted code as is. I get the feeling the posted code as is doesn't crash, though, despite the memory leak.

Comment: @Jueecy: Are you sure that's invalid?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, no, not sure anymore.

Comment: I just want to remind that, everything is alright without string in structure

Comment: @DamianWoroszył, Most likely a red herring because of some other undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DamianWoroszył , your code with the above edits will work fine.

Comment: @Jueecy, yes i had code like this before, but if i pass the array to the function in that way and then i use delete[] on the_arr will i delete the abc array itself?

Comment: @DamianWoroszył, you are not passing the array, you are passing a pointer to the heap, that's all. `delete[]` will make a recursive delete on all elements, deallocating them from the heap. Therefore: yes. It will delete the memory you have allocated on the array.

Comment: Now i know everything i wanted to know and got some extra knowledge as well, thanks

Comment: Yes, but how do i do it? (It was first time i asked a question here)

Comment: @DamianWoroszył, you did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the vector or other sequence objects. Though I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your code. Here's a quick example:

```
// Vector represent a sequence which can change in size
vector<Student*> students;

// Create your student, I just filled in a bunch of crap for the
// sake of creating an example
Student * newStudent = new Student;
newStudent->a = 1;
newStudent->b = 2;
newStudent->name = "Guy McWhoever";
newStudent->status = 'A';

// and I pushed the student onto the vector
students.push_back( newStudent );
students.push_back( newStudent );
students.push_back( newStudent );
students.push_back( newStudent );
```

Comment: He said he can't use vectors. Probably because this is homework.

Comment: Anyway, use a vector of `Student`, not a vector of `Student *`.